# How to detect clicks on links in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I use this code to check if a user touched inside a webview

```
                webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
                {  
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                    {
                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        {
                                //action

                        }  
                      return false;
                    }
                });
```

but I will need to do action only if user clicked (touched ) a link only ,not if the the user touch some pictures or do a scrool in webview.
I need to reinit some variables when new webpage is loaded ,or when a user clicks on a link , but not when he click random on screen or he do scrool.
i can not use

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
```

or

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

cause this are called multiple times while a page is loaded and I only need to do action first time only 1 time , when user click on a link  (or button or something that make webview to load a new page)

Does anybody knwo how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first step - enable JavaScript:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

second step - create interface between Java and Javascript:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

register your interface:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

and put this JS in your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

example for html:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
```

if pages which you are showing are not your you might download them as plain text, then insert JS and load html with [myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). this way you have full control of which user is clicking and what to do with it

to be honest I don't understand why you cannot do this with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` by checking what is arriving in `url` String and setting 'consumed' flag or smth like this

also: whole code is stolen from [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)